# The sum of triangular functions

Tags: gm.general-mathematics

I have a sum of $N-1$ triangular functions to calculate and it is $$s = \sum_{q=0}^{N-1} \frac{W_q \left(\cos\left(\dfrac{n\pi q}{N}\right) + \cos\left(\dfrac{(n-1)\pi q}{N}\right)\right) }{ 1 + \cos\left(\dfrac{\pi q}{N}\right)},$$ where $W_q = 1$ except $W_0 = \dfrac12$. It indeed has analytical result $N-n+\dfrac12$ and I can't get it.

Comment: Is $W_q$ a (constant) function or a constant?

Comment: Wq = 1 for q=1, 2, 3, ..., N-1; Wq = 0.5 for q=0

Comment: for $n=0$ it sums to $N-1/2$ not to $N+1/2$.

Comment: Dear Carlo, could you show me the detailed derivation process?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume (which seems to be implicit in the question) that $0 < n \le N$. I'm also going to parameterise $s$ for clarity.

Then your expression simplifies to

$$s_{N,n} = \frac12 + \sum_{q=1}^{N-1} \frac{\cos\left(\frac{n\pi q}{N}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi q}{N}\right)}{1 + \cos\left(\frac{\pi q}{N}\right)} = \frac12 + \sum_{q=1}^{N-1} \frac{T_n(\cos q\theta_N) + T_{n-1}(\cos q\theta_N)}{1 + \cos q\theta_N}$$
where $\theta_N = \frac{\pi}{N}$ and $T_n$ is the $n$th Chebyshev polynomial (of the first kind).

There's a less well known family of polynomials called the [Chebyshev polynomials of the third kind](https://oeis.org/A228565), defined by $$V_0(x) = 1;   \qquad   V_1(x) = 2x - 1;   \qquad   V_n(x) = 2xV_{n-1}(x) - V_{n-2}(x)$$

**Theorem**: for $n > 0$ we have $T_n(x) + T_{n-1}(x) = (1+x)V_{n-1}(x)$. Proof is by induction, using the identity $V_n(x) + V_{n-1}(x) = 2T_n(x)$ from the OEIS link.
Then $$s_{N,n} = \frac12 + \sum_{q=1}^{N-1} V_{n-1}(\cos q\theta_N)$$

Note that we only care about the even exponents of $V_n$, because $\sum_{q=1}^{N-1} \cos^{2k+1} q\theta_N = 0$ for integer $k \neq 0$, by matching pairs of $q$ which sum to $N$ and using $\cos q\theta_N = -\cos (N-q)\theta_N$.

From Barry's [On the Group of Almost-Riordan Arrays](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05077.pdf) (linked in the OEIS page above) we have $$V_n(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{n/2} (-1)^j B^2_{n-j,j} x^{n-2j} - \sum_{j=0}^{(n-1)/2} (-1)^j B^2_{n-j-1,j} x^{n-2j-1}$$ where $B^2_{n,j} = \sum_i \binom ni \binom ij$. Then filtering to even exponents,

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{q=1}^{N-1} V_{2k}(\cos q\theta_N)   &=  & \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j B^2_{2k-j,j} \sum_{q=1}^{N-1} \cos^{2(k-j)} q\theta_N \\
\sum_{q=1}^{N-1} V_{2k+1}(\cos q\theta_N) &= -& \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j B^2_{2k-j,j} \sum_{q=1}^{N-1} \cos^{2(k-j)} q\theta_N
\end{eqnarray*}$$

It's probably simpler to reindex $j$: $$\sum_{q=1}^{N-1} V_{2k}(\cos q\theta_N) = -\sum_{q=1}^{N-1} V_{2k+1}(\cos q\theta_N) = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j} B^2_{k+j,k-j} \sum_{q=1}^{N-1} \cos^{2j} q\theta_N$$

Then

$$s_{N,2k+1} = \frac12 + \sum_{q=1}^{N-1} V_{2k}(\cos q\theta_N) = \frac12 + \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j} B^2_{k+j,k-j} \sum_{q=1}^{N-1} \cos^{2j} q\theta_N \\
s_{N,2k+2} = \frac12 + \sum_{q=1}^{N-1} V_{2k+1}(\cos q\theta_N) = \frac12 - \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j} B^2_{k+j,k-j} \sum_{q=1}^{N-1} \cos^{2j} q\theta_N$$

Note that since $0 < n \le N$, we certainly have $j \le k = \lfloor \tfrac{n-1}2 \rfloor < N$.

---

Greening showed in *A trigonometric summation*, Amer. Math. Monthly, 75 (1968), 405-406 that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} 4^\mu \cos^{2\mu} \tfrac{k \pi}{n+1} = (n+1) \binom{2\mu - 1}{\mu - 1} - 2^{2\mu - 1}$$ when $0 < \mu < n+1$.

With suitable substitutions (including $\binom{2j-1}{j-1} = \frac12 \binom{2j}{j}$) we get

$$\sum_{q=1}^{\lfloor (N-1)/2 \rfloor} \cos^{2j} q \theta_N = \frac{1}{2^{2j+1}} \binom{2j}{j} N - \frac12$$ when $0 < j < N$.

By symmetry we fill in the other half; when there's a term for $1 \le q < N$ which isn't accounted for in either then it's $\cos^{2j} \tfrac\pi 2 = 0$. The case $j=0$ is trivial; and we get

$$\sum_{q=1}^{N-1} \cos^{2j} q\theta_N = \frac{1}{2^{2j}} \binom{2j}{j} N - 1$$ when $0 \le j < N$.

---

So under the constraints described,

$$\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j} B^2_{k+j,k-j} \sum_{q=1}^{N-1} \cos^{2j} q\theta_N
 = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j} B^2_{k+j,k-j} \left( \frac{1}{2^{2j}} \binom{2j}{j} N - 1 \right) \\
 = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j} \left( \frac{1}{4^j} \binom{2j}{j} N - 1 \right) \sum_i \binom{k+j}{i} \binom{i}{k-j} \\
 = \left( \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j} \frac{1}{4^j} \binom{2j}{j} \sum_i \binom{k+j}{i} \binom{i}{k-j} \right) N -
   \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j} \sum_i \binom{k+j}{i} \binom{i}{k-j} \\
 = N - (2k + 1)$$ where the final binomial sum reduction is handled by a CAS.

So

$$s_{N,2k+1} = \tfrac12 + N - 2k - 1 = N - (2k+1) + \tfrac12 \\
  s_{N,2k+2} = \tfrac12 - N + 2k + 1 = -(N - (2k+2) + \tfrac12)$$

or, combining the cases, $$s_{N,n} = (-1)^{n+1} (N - n + \tfrac12)$$ subject to $0 < n \le N$.

Answer (score 0):

Solving for definite $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ I find something a bit more complicated than what is written in the OP:

$$\frac{1}{2}+\sum _{q=1}^{N-1} \frac{\cos (\pi  (n-1) q/N)+\cos (\pi  n q/N)}{\cos (\pi q/N)+1}=\begin{cases}(-1)^{n}\left(N+n-\frac{1}{2}\right) &\text{if}\;\;n\leq 0,\\
(-1)^{n+1}\left(N-n+\frac{1}{2}\right) &\text{if}\;\;n>0.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: typo corrected, thanks.

Comment: Hi Carlo, do you have the detailed process to get it?

Comment: I used Mathematica for definite $n$, it does not return a closed form expression for arbitrary $n$.

Comment: I found $cos(x) - cos(2x) + cos(3x) - ...cos(nx) = 0.5 -(-1)^{n+1} \frac {cos(nx) + cos(n+1)x} {1+cosx}$. However I cannot go further.

Comment: @WangWangshen further you change the order of summation and sum up the cosines along arithmetic progression

Comment: @FedorPetrov where is the arithmetic progression?

Comment: $x=\pi q/N$ runs over arithmetic progression when $q$ varies, so does $2x$ etc